# Scroll to Fieldset When Link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have an example of what I have so far [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RGMLP/1/)

obvious this is not working because the PHP, let alone the jQuery. 
its just to show what I am doing.

I want to be able to click on the `href`, and this will scroll to the `fieldset` with the appropriate title.

Can anyone help, seems simple but cant get it to work ?

Comment: I assume in your actual code you're running this on a PHP web server, and that PHP generates actual HTML/JavaScript? If yes, use whatever your server returns to build your jsFiddle example. As a general rule, if you're not asking about a problem with the server-side implementation (the PHP, in this case) but the client-side stuff, your question and example code should **not** contain server-side code, but whatever that code generates and sends to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Apply an id to each fieldset and use this code:

```
    function scrollForMe(top){
    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: top.offset().top
    }, 1000, "easeOutExpo");
}
```

Use it like so:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
    scrollForMe($("#fieldesetname1"));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Apologies, that was just the class i gave the link - it appears you gave it a class of "link" which i will amend

Comment: oh thanks, I cannot get this working? its strange.  I declare the two functions in the head,, and have a href with a link class? , this should work but its not, i have an alert statment in the function and that is not even working